# Not able to connect using imap_open ()

Tags: php

I am trying to connect and fetch messages of my hosting's email address using imap_open(), but its throwing errors.

```
$server = '{mail.booksnearby.in:143/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$imap_connection = imap_open($server, $login, $password);
$mailboxinfo = imap_mailboxmsginfo($imap_connection);
$messageCount = $mailboxinfo->Nmsgs;
```

The above throws this error: `Array ( [0] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.`

If I change $server to

```
$server = '{mail.booksnearby.in:143}INBOX';
```

then it throws the following error

```
Certificate failure for mail.booksnearby.in: self signed certificate:
```

If $server is

```
$server = '{mail.booksnearby.in:143/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

it throws

```
Array ( [0] => TLS/SSL failure for mail.booksnearby.in: SSL negotiation failed )
```

I can connect to the email account using an email client, with the same username password.

I can't seem to telnet in as well. Its running apache , cpanel and dovecat. Imap with Ssl support is enabled on my hosting..

Answer (score 16):

Are you sure that the port number is 143 (not 993)? Cause you are using a secure connection with self signed certificate as I see.
Try to do that this way:

```
$server = '{mail.booksnearby.in:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

Comment: May be 3 years old but this answer just saved my life.

Comment: Mine too, 8 years later. :-)

Comment: 10 years later xD

Comment: 12 years later and "/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert" saved me :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but is still relevant:)

Usually, when the port `143` is used there is no SSL encryption involved. 
So you don't need to set `ssl` in your connection string.
As a result, it should look like:

```
$server = '{mail.booksnearby.in:143/imap}INBOX';
```

Hope this will help.